# Magento overriding the core files

Tags: php, magento

I have a problem with overriding the core file. 
Basic path is **app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/List.php**

My module structure:

```
CompanyName/
  ModuleName/
    Block/
      Product/
        List.php
    etc/
      config.xml
```

My files:
**app/etc/modules/CompanyName_ModuleName.xml**

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <CompanyName_ModuleName>
            <active>true</active>
            <codepool>local</codepool>
        </CompanyName_ModuleName>
    </modules>
</config>
```

**../CompanyName/ModuleName/etc/config.xml**

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <CompanyName_ModuleName>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </CompanyName_ModuleName>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <CompanyName_ModuleName>
                <class>CompanyName_ModuleName_Block</class>
            </CompanyName_ModuleName>
            <catalog>
                <rewrite>
                    <product_list>CompanyName_ModuleName_Block_Product_List</product_list>
                </rewrite>
            </catalog>
        </blocks>
    </global>
</config>
```

and **../CompanyName/ModuleName/Block/Product/List.php**

```
class CompanyName_ModuleName_Block_Product_List extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List
{
    public function _getProductCollection()
    {
      (...)
    }
}
```

I don't know why it doesn't work. I can't see the mistake.

Comment: enable the logs form backend and then check the system.log , what error is showing ?

Comment: i think you have to follow the CompanyName as Companyname and ModuleName as Modulename.... some times it also create the problem ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a typo in your case. In your `CompanyName_ModuleName.xml`, it should be

```
<codePool>local</codePool>
```

Note the camel-letter `P` in `codePool`. Due to this typo, magento most probably didn't activated your module. That is why nothing happens through your module

Also for rewrite a block, you don't want define block section. This is enough in `config.xml` under `global` node

```
     <blocks>
        <catalog>
            <rewrite>
                <product_list>CompanyName_ModuleName_Block_Product_List</product_list>
            </rewrite>
        </catalog>
    </blocks>
```

Please note your module should reside in `local` codepool. Please ensure that also.

Always try to avoid unwanted camel-letters in `Namespace` and in `modulename`. It is not wrong actually. But instead of `CompanyName_ModuleName`, you can use `Companyname_Modulename`. It would helps you to avoid unwanted typos.

It is a small recommendation from my part

Eventhough you dont need the following part in your config.xml, I would like to mention one thing here. If your module has its own block inside it, except rewriting blocks, you should have this code in your config.xml

```
<global>
     <companyname_modulename> <!-- unique identifier; block reference -->
                <class>CompanyName_ModuleName_Block</class>
    <companyname_modulename>
     ....
</global>
```

Later you will going to refer your blocks using the unique identifier `companyname_modulename`. The rule for specifying this reference node is "It should be unique". By convention, module name is 
used for this. So in this case, convention says, you have to use `modulename` as block reference. But some time, there is a chance to make conflict with other custom extensions, if we use only module name as the reference.So in order to ensure this one is unique, I strongly recommend `namespace_modulename` format. Note that I used small letters. In your case you used Camel-letters also. It is not a good practice.

But the above thing is not relevant in your case. Since your module does not hold any blocks of your module itself, but only a rewrite block. So the above mentioned part of code is not necessary for you. This is because, in rewrite section, we are explicitly tells magento that where should it look for that rewrite block. In your case, you are specifying it like `CompanyName_ModuleName_Block_Product_List`.

Hope that make sense.

Comment: So always remember about `codePool`. :) if it helped accept it as answer. Also read my updated answer

Comment: The `codePool` rock has been slammed into by many a programmer. One of those irritating pebbles you get in your shoe that can sink a freight liner. <grin>

Comment: @FiascoLabs:Once that pebble found out and and thrown away from shoe, then next time you will not going to make that mistake. You always concern about that situation. I had it once inside my shoe. That's why I figured it out. :)